# Vuejs - When to use v-for? v-html?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When displaying a list of items using VueJS, it is obviously easy to do using `v-for` directive. The same thing can be achieved by using a `computed` property to return html and display using `v-html`.

```
<ul>
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <li><span class=myItem">{{ item }}</span></li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

vs.

```
<div v-html="compiledHtmlList"></div>
```

I noticed, for my use case, `v-html` renders a string list of about 30K items few seconds faster than `v-for`. As I am new to VueJS, wondering if the difference in performance is expected, and if so, why? If not, are there other reasons for choosing one over the other?

Comment: Try changing just one item in the list and compare render times (for the change only)

Comment: I expect for update only `v-for` would be faster. I did an eye test earlier, but didn't feel any difference. Unfortunately code is on work computer; will definitely test it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

v-for is slower to load but it's faster when the list changes. v-html will have a faster loading time, but that loading time will be the same as the update time.

So, if the list is static and it won't change during the time it's rendered (like a list of items that can be deleted), you could use v-html, but if that list could change, use v-for.

Comment: This makes sense. Could you explain further on what Vue is doing under the hood that makes v-for faster at updating? is it making some kind of index on the dom elements?